# Usando o Circle como uma máscara com o Google Maps Api V3

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, front-end, google-maps-api-3

Tenho um círculo, e retângulos múltiplos, que eu pinto com algumas cores, mas, eu apenas quero ver as cores dentro do círculo, não fora dele.

[Exemplo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MLx5I.png)

Eu só quero ver as cores do círculo interno, pensei se usasse o círculo como uma máscara, mas não encontrei a solução nos atributos de círculo do google maps.

Comment: Matheus, o pt.stackoverflow deve ser usado apenas para perguntas em português. Tenta traduzir o questionamento ou joga ele lá no https://stackoverflow.com/

Comment: ops, desculpe-me kkk, vou jogar lá e traduzir aqui :)